# UML High Level Class Diagram

Tags: uml, class-diagram, high-level

can somebody please explains what is a high level class diagram. As far as I know class diagram shows the association between the classes but what about high level class diagram??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I knew what this means, a Class Diagram contains many details. A high-level class diagram is a simple class diagram reflecting only initial domain knowledge

Answer (score 0):

What's the context?  Class diagrams in themselves are pretty "high-level", in that they only show classes and methods rather than algorithms and other implementation details.  It might just be an adjective.  Or, you might be looking for something more like a [block-level diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_diagram) which shows components of a system and how they interact.

Comment: I'm doing a project, in my design, I've placed a class diagram but my supervisor said to me to place a high level diagram in analysis

Answer (score 0):

I often use the term "high-level", or more usually, "top-level" diagram for the very highest level class diagram I make for a system.  Usually this will show as many of the most important packages as will reasonably fit, along with some classes that give the best idea of what  functionality the classes in that package provide.  From there I can do class diagrams of each package, and so on.

Depending on the type of system and what your supervisor want to see, you may be better off creating a **[component diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_diagram)**.